# Jquery Mobile Drop Down menu not functioning in PHP properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, navigation

So the mobile drop down was working perfectly in a separate project, but when I dropped it into a PHP project it just stopped behaving properly.

Now, everytime the link is chosen, it goes to the link, but the drop down doesn't stay on the current page, it jumps back to the first selection available. Making it impossible to actually go to that page.

Thinking that the PHP somewhere is interfering, but I'll be if I can't seem to diagnose the issue... Have some idea's, but... anyways, here's some code.

JS:

```
var $select = $("<select></select>");
$("#menu").append($select);

$("#menu a").each(function(){
var $anchor = $(this);
var $option = $("<option></option>");
if ($anchor.parent().hasClass('selected')) {
  $option.prop('selected', true);
}
$option.val($anchor.attr("href"));
$option.text($anchor.text());
$select.append($option);
});


  $select.change(function(){
    window.location = $select.val();
  });
```

MENU:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>diamonds/">diamonds</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>jewelry/">jewelry</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>coin/">coin & Bullion</a></li>            
      <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact/">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```